# Unable to add Image to pdf file from mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, itext

```
Document myDocument = new Document();
                    PdfWriter myWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(myDocument, 
new FileOutputStream(filePath));
                    myDocument.open();
                    Blob imageBlob = rs.getBlob("Signature");
                    byte[] imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) 
imageBlob.length());
                    Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
                    image.scaleAbsolute(300,300);
                    myDocument.add(image);
```

I am trying to get Image from the database stored in the data type of medium blob. I have tried everything and checked various codes on stackoverflow but not bale to resolve an error. Each time it is showing that getInstance() method not found.

Comment: Are you sure you imported the iText `Image` class and not e.g. the awt class?

Comment: I usually ignore questions in which the OP claims "I have tried everything." If *everything* was already tried, why would I bother? Especially when the OP calls himself "Master". Moreover: you're using iText 5 or earlier. Why don't you try iText 7? Are you sure you visited the official iText web site (because I don't think you did).

Comment: Your question is incomplete. You need to add everything you tried.

Comment: Have you tried to write the image bytes through awt to your file system and see if the image isn't corrupted?

Comment: @mkl thanks buddy it was having some issue while importing the class.. Your suggestion worked... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For

```
byte[] imageBytes = imageBlob.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob.length());
Image image = Image.getInstance(imageBytes);
```

you get a "getInstance() method not found" error.

As the iText `Image` class clearly does have a static `getInstance` method with a single `byte[]` argument, this indicates that the `Image` class here does not refer to the iText `Image` class but instead to a different one, probably the awt `Image` class.

Thus, look at your imports, probably you import some whole packages which may contain their own `Image` class and so mask the iText `Image` class.

Comment: Exactly @mkl.. Can you help me to create Required Field validation in swings form..

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: Basically i am trying to say is i want user to input his name.. if he does not entered name or name is null the form will not be submitted moreover the user will get a highlighted text to enter his name. It is similar to RequiredField validator in .net frameworks. I am not able to do that task in swing form. @mkl

Comment: I hardly know Swing anymore. So I'm afraid I cannot help you with that.

Comment: No problem .. Thanks for above solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
Blob imageBlob1 = rs.getBlob("Image");
byte[] imageBytes1 = imageBlob1.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob1.length());
com.itextpdf.text.Image image1 = com.itextpdf.text.Image.getInstance(imageBytes1);
image1.scaleToFit(80f, 350f);
image1.setAbsolutePosition(430,680);
image1.scaleAbsoluteWidth(70);
image1.scaleAbsoluteHeight(80);
myDocument.add(image1);
```

The above code worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This code is working for me

```
try {
    String sql1 = " Select foto from ishirahamwe.abanywanyi where numero = \'" + strId + "\'";
    Statement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql1);
    rs = statement.executeQuery(sql1);
    if (rs.next()) {
                    
        Blob imageBlob1 = rs.getBlob("foto");
        byte[] imageBytes1 = imageBlob1.getBytes(1, (int) imageBlob1.length());
        com.lowagie.text.Image image1 = com.lowagie.text.Image.getInstance(imageBytes1);
        image1.scaleToFit(80f, 350f);
        image1.setAbsolutePosition(430,680);
        image1.scaleAbsoluteWidth(70);
        image1.scaleAbsoluteHeight(80);
        document.add(image1);

    }

} catch (Exception e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
}
```